# How can I insert a specific number of elements in a list?

Tags: c, list, singly-linked-list

I tried to insert a specific number of elements (fourplets from a struct that each of them represents a packet) in the list by using size_t n but when I run the main programm it does not display nothing. How can I define the size in the insert function, so that when more packets(fourplets) are trying to insert the list, they will not be able because of the list's size?

```
    struct Packet
    {
     int rollnumber;
     int src;
     int dest;
     double gentime;
     struct Packet *next;
    }* head;

  void insert(int rollnumber, int src, int dest, double gentime, size_t n)
   {
     if (n==0) n=(size_t)-1;
     struct Packet * packet = (struct Packet *) malloc(sizeof(struct Packet));
     for ( struct Packet * temp = head; n-- && temp != NULL; temp = temp->next ){
       packet->rollnumber = rollnumber;
       packet->src=src;
       packet->dest=dest;
       packet->gentime = gentime;
       packet->next = NULL;

       if(head==NULL){
          head = packet;
       }
       else{
          packet->next = head;
          head = packet;
       }
    }

    }

     
    void display()
    {
     struct Packet * temp = head;
     while(temp != NULL)
     {
       printf("Roll Number: %d\n",temp->rollnumber);
       printf("src: %d\n", temp->src);
       printf("dest: %d\n", temp->dest);
       printf("gentime: %0.1f\n\n", temp->gentime);
       temp = temp->next;
      }
   }
```

Comment: In the `insert` function, you want to insert into `n` copies into a linked-list of the same element? Sounds like this should be broken into two functions.

Comment: Not copies. I want to  insert in the list n number of packets(also fourplets) and I want this number n to be known from the size_t n, so that when more packets come, they will be rejected.

Comment: So you want to create the node, then insert it `n` spaces away in the linked-list who's pointer is a global variable, `head`?

Comment: I think you got the point! I just want to have a list that will have specific number of nodes, let's say 10, so when 15 packets come to be inserted, the 5 of them will be rejected because of the size of the list.

Comment: Would you would be better suited with a circular array (of size 10) and not a linked-list?

Comment: A list was what my professor asked for, so an array would not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** new code below is a complete working example.  It should give you enough of a start to go for the rest.

You created the packet above but never actually put it into your chain.  This creates it and tries to find the right spot to insert it:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Packet
{
   int rollnumber;
   int src;
   int dest;
   double gentime;
   struct Packet *next;
}* head;

void insert(int rollnumber, int src, int dest, double gentime, size_t n)
{
    /* Assuming you're trying to insert these values at point n */

    if (n >= 15) {
        printf("no %d!\n", n);
        return;
    }

    /* create the packet to insert */
    struct Packet * packet = (struct Packet *) malloc(sizeof(struct Packet));
    packet->rollnumber = rollnumber;
    packet->src=src;
    packet->dest=dest;
    packet->gentime = gentime;
    packet->next = NULL;

    /* now find the point where it should be inserted */
    if (n == 0 || head == NULL) {
        /* it should be first! */
        packet->next = head;
        head = packet;
    } else {
        struct Packet *temp = head;
        for ( ; n > 1 && temp != NULL && temp->next != NULL ; temp = temp->next, n-- ){
        }
        if (temp != NULL) {
            /* put ourselves in the middle (or the end if packet->next is NULL) */
            packet->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = packet;
        }
    }
}

void display()
{
    printf("-----------------\n");
    struct Packet * temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("Roll Number: %d\n",temp->rollnumber);
            printf("src: %d\n", temp->src);
            printf("dest: %d\n", temp->dest);
            printf("gentime: %0.1f\n\n", temp->gentime);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
}

int main() {
    insert(1,1,1,1,10); /* legal, will just append */
    display();

    insert(2,2,2,2,0); /* insert before 1 */
    display();

    insert(3,3,3,3,2); /* insert after 2 */
    display();

    insert(4,4,4,4,1); /* after 2, and before 3 */
    display();

    insert(5,5,5,5,15); /* illegal */
}
```

Comment: Still does not displays nothing. Maybe is there something with my display function?

Comment: I want to have a list that will have specific number of nodes, let's say 10, so when 15 packets (also each fourplet) come to be inserted, the 5 of them will be rejected because of the size of the list.

Comment: I've updated it -- it should give you enough to get going.